# Export data frame as csv to different drive

Tags: python, pandas

My working directory is in C:\users\myname\Documents\Github....
I want this csv to save to a different drive Z:. I tried using os.path.relpath(), but got this

```
path is on mount 'Z:', start on mount 'C:'
```

What I think this means is that it can't find a path because they are on different drives. Is it even possible to export to a different drive?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code has been written in pandas. If you want to save your `.csv` file to drive Z, you can simply do so by:

```
df.to_csv('Z:/Github/data.csv')
```